React Build error on Server: Unexpected token '<'
I'm getting an error in my React app only after I build on my server. This error doesn't happen on my local machine.
I'm getting an error that says: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.9ade8857.js:1:1)"
enter image description here
This is a simplified code example as this issue is impacting several other more serious apps:
//index.html file:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>



//index.js file:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);



//App.js file
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <h1>Hosting Home Page</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


I was expecting the build version on my server to work exactly like my dev version on my local machine.  No changes were made. Just deployed the app.

Where’s your server code?
